# Gxt 3 Neptune Theme Setup Issue

Tags: extjs, themes, gxt

I just installed GXT SDK 2.6 and created a new google web project.

added the following jars to the lib folder and to the build path
`gxt-3.1.1.jar`
`gxt-theme-neptune.jar`

but when i run my page on the browser i get the following error pls help.

```
[ERROR] [ia] - Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Anant%20Choubey/Eclipse%20Workspace/GXT%20-%20IA%20-%2003Oct2014/IA/lib/gxt-theme-neptune.jar!/com/sencha/gxt/theme/neptune/client/base/Css3ThemeAppearance.java'
[ERROR] [ia] - Line 58: The method moreIcon() of type Css3ThemeAppearance must override or implement a supertype method
```

I have made no other changes elsewhere.

Comment: Sounds like you're not using the latest version of `gxt-theme-neptune.jar` (3.1.1). You can download it here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sencha.gxt/gxt-theme-neptune

Comment: Thanks Darek, yes i replaced the JAR and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have **old version** of theme plugin. Download new gxt-theme-neptune.jar-3.1.1 and try again.

[Download link of gxt-theme-neptune.jar-3.1.1...](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sencha/gxt/gxt-theme-neptune/3.1.1/gxt-theme-neptune-3.1.1.jar)

Comment: Actually I had the same problem and solved by doing this. So I just suggest here...